# network connection errors when running do-release-upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade to 15.10 with do-release-upgrade, but I get the errors posted below.  I have no problem with "apt-get".  My http_proxy environment variable is set---I have it in /etc/environment.  How can I do the update?

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [198 B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,232 kB]
Fetched 1,232 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
authenticate 'wily.tar.gz' against 'wily.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'wily.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
Err http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security InRelease
Err [link] vivid-security Release.gpg
Cannot initiate the connection to [link] (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
Err http://archive.canonical.com vivid InRelease
Err [link] vivid Release.gpg                                             
Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::16 80]
Err [link] vivid InRelease
```

Comment: It looks that you have only ipv6 protocol enabled.

Comment: Would that make a difference?  I disabled ipv6 and got the same behavior, but with different looking IP addresses in the errors.

Comment: It looks like you are behind a proxy or some other way blocked from internet.

Comment: Yes, I'm behind a proxy, but I've set the http_proxy environment vars and added the proxy to apt.conf.  All other network connections work fine.  I can run apt-get and it works fine with the proxy.  Why won't do-release-upgrade work?